# inside out creation of database

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, s#arp-architecture

I usually have no problem 'seeding' my database via NHibernate like this:

```
...
string[] mappingAssemblies = new string[] { "Bla.Di.Domain" };
string configFile = "NHibernate.config";
NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration config = NHibernateSession.Init(
    new SimpleSessionStorage(),
    mappingAssemblies,
    new AutoPersistenceModelGenerator().Generate(),
    configFile);

TextWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter("d:/SeedSQL.sql");

var session = NHibernateSession.GetDefaultSessionFactory().OpenSession();
new SchemaExport(config).Execute(true, true, false, session.Connection, writeFile);
```

For some reason the database is not created for the above dll (Bla.Di.Domain) with a simple class like this:

```
namespace Bla.Di.Domain
{
    using SharpArch.Domain.DomainModel;

    public class Test : Entity
    {
        public virtual string X { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Is there anything that could have gone potentially go wrong? I do not get an exception. I referenced the dll in my 'seeding' project. Maybe there is an issue with the file location of my dll (it is a fairly complicated solution). Thanks.

PS (as requested in comment):

This is my AutoPersistenceModelGenerator - please note that it lives in another namespace:

```
public class AutoPersistenceModelGenerator : IAutoPersistenceModelGenerator
{
    public AutoPersistenceModel Generate()
    {
        //var mappings = AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Bla>(new AutomappingConfiguration());
        var mappings = AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Test>(new AutomappingConfiguration());
        mappings.IgnoreBase<Entity>();
        mappings.IgnoreBase(typeof(EntityWithTypedId<>));
        mappings.Conventions.Setup(GetConventions());
        mappings.UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<AutoPersistenceModelGenerator>();

        return mappings;
    }

    private static Action<IConventionFinder> GetConventions()
    {
        return c =>
           {
               c.Add<PrimaryKeyConvention>();
               c.Add<CustomForeignKeyConvention>();
               c.Add<HasManyConvention>();
               c.Add<TableNameConvention>();
           };
    }
}
```

I have added a reference to the domain model (different name space) and changed:

```
var mappings = AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Bla>(new AutomappingConfiguration());
```

to:

```
var mappings = AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Test>(new AutomappingConfiguration());
```

Comment: I think the problem has to do with the AutoPersistenceModelGenerator which is in a different namespace. Not yet sure what to do ...

Comment: paste the code of AutoPersistenceModelGenerator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us say we have two namespaces: CompanyName.X and CompanyName.Y.

CompanyName.X contains class A and CompanyName.Y contains B, where A and B inherit from Entity. Then this adaptation helps:

Original:

```
public class AutoPersistenceModelGenerator : IAutoPersistenceModelGenerator
{
    public AutoPersistenceModel Generate()
    {
        var mappings = AutoMap.AssemblyOf<A>(new AutomappingConfiguration());
        mappings.IgnoreBase<Entity>();
        mappings.IgnoreBase(typeof(EntityWithTypedId<>));
        mappings.Conventions.Setup(GetConventions());
        mappings.UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<AutoPersistenceModelGenerator>();

        return mappings;
    }
    ...
```

Adapted code:

```
public class AutoPersistenceModelGenerator : IAutoPersistenceModelGenerator
{
    public AutoPersistenceModel Generate()
    {
        var mappings = AutoMap.AssemblyOf<A>(new AutomappingConfiguration());
        mappings.AddEntityAssembly(typeof(CompanyName.Y.B).Assembly);
        mappings.IgnoreBase<Entity>();
        mappings.IgnoreBase(typeof(EntityWithTypedId<>));
        mappings.Conventions.Setup(GetConventions());
        mappings.UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<AutoPersistenceModelGenerator>();

        return mappings;
    }
    ...
```